# find a matrix of the operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Consider the operator $$L(p) = x^2p'' + p' − 3p$$ from the space P2 of
polynomials of degree ≤ 2 to itself. Find a matrix of the operator in a
basis of P2. Find its eigenvalues, bases of the eigenspaces, and check if
it is diagonalizable.
I know how to find eigenvalues, bases of eigenspaces, and check if diagonalizable, but I don't know how to find a matrix of the operator so that I can then do those things.

Answer (score 2):

It is easy to check that the operation is linear.

Then, we know that the basis has three elements ($1$, $x$, $x^2$), so the matrix must be $3 \times 3$.

We also know that the **columns** of the matrix corresponds to the transformation of the three bases elements.

Namely:

$\begin{array}{rcl}
L(1) &=& -3 \\
L(x) &=& 1-3x \\
L(x^2) &=& 2x^2 + 2x - 3x^2 = -x^2+2x
\end{array}$

Therefore, our matrix is:

$\begin{pmatrix}-3&1&0\\0&-3&2\\0&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$

With each column representing the result of each transformation above.

Answer (score 0):

First find a basis of polynomials of degree $\leq 2,$ then see how your operators acts on that basis, and you will have your matrix.